# Why can't @SafeVarags be applied to instance methods in a final class?

Tags: java, annotations, overriding, variadic-functions, type-erasure

According to the [documentation of `SafeVarargs`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SafeVarargs.html), the `@SafeVarargs` annotation can be applied only to constructors or variable arity methods that are either `static` or `final`. This is, [I have read](http://aruld.info/annotation-type-to-reduce-varargs-warnings-available-in-b123-java-7-coin-minting-done/), to eliminate issues with annotation inheritance; that is to say, annotations on methods are only allowed if the method cannot be overridden. Clearly, constructors, `static` methods, and `final` methods cannot be overridden. However, neither can `private` methods or methods in a `final class`. [Someone has complained](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/213) about the inability to designate `@SafeVarargs private` methods, but [neither of these issues has been addressed](http://ideone.com/9nL33O). In general, [no one really seems to care](https://www.google.com/search?q=%40safevarags+annotation+cannot+be+applied+to+non-final+instance+method&oq=%40safevarags+annotation+cannot+be+applied+to+non-final+instance+method). Am I missing something? Am I complaining about something that doesn't have any practical applications? Or... ?

Comment: Meh, if the use of varargs in a method is safe, I'm inclined to use  a SuppressWarnings annotation to make the compiler stop complaining.  But I'm not sure why you can't use this annotation on methods that are effectively final.

Comment: @jjm If I recall correctly, using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` on a varargs method will suppress the warning at that location, but there will still be warnings wherever that method is used. Thus the _raison d'être_ for `@SafeVarargs`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is scheduled to be fixed in Java 9; see http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/213 .

Comment: I actually linked here from my question, but wasn't sure whether this was an unimportant proposal (free to be ignored) or something that was very likely to go through. I also notice that it (curiously) makes no mention of methods in `final` classes. Do you suppose there is a reason for this other than simple oversight?

Comment: Yes, it's planned for inclusion in JDK9.

Comment: Support for `@SafeVarargs` does appear to be supported in Java 9 and later; however, the annotation still does not work in final classes as of Java 17.